Inquirer library does not work with PyInstaller
I created a script that uses inquirer, but when I created the executable, the import doesn't work.
Simplified the code to just the import:
import inquirer

And generate the executable with the command:
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=inquirer .\test.py

and
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=inquirer --hidden-import=readchar .\test.py

Error traceback:
.\test.exe                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 563, in from_name
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "inquirer\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "inquirer\prompt.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "inquirer\render\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "inquirer\render\console\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "inquirer\events.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "readchar\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 1009, in version
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 982, in distribution
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 565, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for readchar
[23340] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!

I tried with Python versions 3.11.9 and 3.12.1.
venv yes,
inquirer 3.2.4

Metadata for a package can be copied using the --copy-metadata option:

Copy metadata for the specified package. This option can be used multiple times.

Changing the command line to something like this should solve the problem:
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=inquirer --hidden-import=readchar --copy-metadata readchar .\test.py

